# Can netty assign multiple IO threads to the same Channel?

Tags: netty

If I were to code the following code segment:

```
class SimpleHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    ...
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap( 
        new NioServerSocketChannelFactory( 
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 
            10 ));
    b.setPipelineFactory( new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline( new SimpleHandler() );
        }
    });
    b.bind( new InetSocketAddress( p ));
}
```

And assuming the following scenario:

- channel C1 has input
- netty assigns thread T1 to channel C1
- after thread T1 has read all the input from channel C1, and while it is still processing the input, more input arrives at channel C1

My question is: will netty assign a new thread to channel C1 (assuming there are free threads in the thread pool)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once a Thread / Selector is assigned to a Channel it will use the same during all of its life-time. So it will be served by the same all the time.

Comment: Thanks, Norman. So, a channel CANNOT have more than one IO thread assigned to it at any one time, right?

Comment: Would I be correct in saying this arises from limitations arising from select and epoll? Discussed here https://idea.popcount.org/2017-02-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-12/